# Icon not working after ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

I have "Mark as Favorite" icon in one of my application. When I clicks on this icon, "Remove Favorite" icon replaces this icon using ajax. But When I click on "Remove Favorite" icon, it doesn't works. What's the problem? I am working in wordpress and here is my code

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.favr-<?php echo $myID; ?>').on("click",function() {
                            var user_IDs = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                            var current_IDs = '<?php echo $cui ?>'; 

                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: '<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {'ajaxreturn': '102', 'logedid': current_IDs,'ids':user_IDs},
                                success: function(result) {
                                    jQuery('.favr-<?php echo $myID; ?>').html(result);
                                }

                            });
                        });
});
```

and here is icon

```
<i title="Remove Favorite" class="radius icon-heart-empty orange favr-<?php echo $myID; ?>" id="<?php echo $myID;  ?>" ></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach click event to your dynamically created icons:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.favr-<?php echo $myID; ?>', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: You need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in my code, try again.